# How to prove that a t-distribution can be written as a ratio distribution?

Tags: proof, t-distribution

If $X \sim N(0,1)$ and $Y \sim \chi^2(n),$ then it's "known" that $Z = X/\sqrt{Y/n}$ is $t$ distributed.

Is there anywhere a proof for this? That in the end one can see the $t$ distribution?

Comment: This was the original (1908) *definition* of $t$: everything else known about it comes from this characterization.  The Wikipedia article on the Student t distribution provides a reference to [Fisher's 1925 paper](http://www.sothis.ro/user/content/4ef6e90670749a86-student_distribution_1925.pdf).

Comment: Go to an answer of mine in math.SE where the full derivation of the t-density can be found. http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/474733/derivation-of-the-density-function-of-student-t-distribution-from-this-big-integ/480327#480327